# What is exactly the difference between Angular and React tree shaking

Tags: reactjs, angular, tree-shaking

I have read that incremental DOM used in Angular has a huge advantage because it makes application tree shakable since you know what's being used at a compilation time and in virtual DOM you can't really do this. However i can see a few articles describing React tree shaking. At this point i don't really understand what's the deal.

Answer (score 0):

`Tree shaking` - There is no relation between V-DOM or DOM, it is all about the removal of the unused code from the final bundle.

```
That job is really nicely done by bundler like webpack or similar
```

`Tree shaking` is a term commonly used in the JavaScript context for dead-code elimination. It relies on the static structure of ES2015 module syntax, i.e. import and export . The name and concept have been popularized by the ES2015 module bundler rollup. - [Follow here](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/)

Simple Example:

Class where we defined our utility fuctions

```
// util.ts
export const getName = (user: User) => user.name;
export const getAge = () => user.age;
```

user component where we import from the util

```
// user.ts
import { getName } from './util';

const user: User = {
    name: 'Jon Due',
    age: 35
}

const userName = getName(user);
```

As you see, we are not using the `getAge` function so `Tree Shaking` will not include that in our final bundle.

Hope it will help you to understand the concept of Tree shaking.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I understand this, however I've seen that there is also a tree shaking performed in the process of compilation in Angular Ivy and that seems to make a difference. That's why I am confused.

Comment: Angular Ivy is nothing by the internal compiler so it compiles the angular module to native code but the tree shakable work the same, if anything is used then it will be in the final bundle, else eliminated.